# Bringing pets to Germany

Tags: germany, argentina, pets

We live in Misiones, Argentina and have 2 cats. Sooner or later we will go back to Germany (we are Germans) and want to bring our cats.

What do we need to bring our cats with us to Germany in the plane? Like vaccinate them or getting an animal passport (how and where).

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but see http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/921/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-move-my-pets-with-me-to-france for a similar question regarding another EU country. One answer even mentions Germany.

Comment: also related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-can-i-travel-to-germany-with-my-dog

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is to consult the [German Federal Ministry of Food and Agriculture page](http://www.bmel.de/EN/Animals/_Texte/HeimtiereEinreiseregelung.html) on Traveling to EU with Animals.

You qualify for entry from the [listed third countries](http://www.bmel.de/EN/Animals/_Downloads/TravellingWithPets-ThirdCountryList.html) of which Argentina is one you will need:

> - every animal needs to be identified by a clearly distinguishable tattoo or by a microchip (mandatory since 3 July 2011 for newly tagged animals) and
> - valid vaccine protection against rabies must be documented in a supporting document (inactivated vaccine with a of at least one antigenic unit per dose in accordance with WHO standard. The vaccine's period of validity is based on the information provided by the manufacturer. In in doubt, please ask your veterinarian. An initial vaccination must be administered at least 21 days before the border is crossed.

You can probably review the information from [German Missions in the US](http://www.germany.info/pets) as it has a lot of information that is similar to importing pets from Argentina or possibly contact [German Embassy in Buenos Aires](http://www.buenos-aires.diplo.de/) to see if there are any specifics for Argentina beyond those listed above.